# How to add new key value paire into same object inside a NSMutable array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutablearray` like this

`

```
(NSMutableArray *) $4 = 0x1d558bb0 <__NSArrayM 0x1d558bb0>(
{
id = 4;
name = "Affection Songs";
noOfSongs = 11;
},
{
id = 11;
name = "Aurudu Songs";
noOfSongs = 7;
},
{
id = 2;
name = "Birth Day Songs";
noOfSongs = 1;
},
{
id = 41;
name = "Broken heart song";
noOfSongs = 85;
},
```

`

What I want to do is add another key value paire for each of these object. So My new NSMutable array should be like this

`

```
(NSMutableArray *) $4 = 0x1d558bb0 <__NSArrayM 0x1d558bb0>(
{
id = 4;
name = "Affection Songs";
noOfSongs = 11;
status = "Check";
},
{
id = 11;
name = "Aurudu Songs";
noOfSongs = 7;
status = "UnCheck";
},
{
id = 2;
name = "Birth Day Songs";
noOfSongs = 1;
status = "Check";
},
{
id = 41;
name = "Broken heart song";
noOfSongs = 85;
status = "Check";
},
```

`

How I can add a new key value paire for this existing `NSMutablearray`'s objects. I have to add this values by checking a each id with another strings.

Please tell me how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: I tryed to get each object through a forloop and add to a NSMutable array but I dont know how to add this key value paire inside the same object,, its adding as another object to my NSMutable array

Comment: @user2889249 can you vote up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
for(int i=0;i<[YourArray count];i++)
{
     NSMutableDictionary *objectDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[YourArray objectAtIndex:i]];
     [objectDict setObject:@"status value" forKey:@"status"];
     [YourArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:objectDict];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I Hope this code will help you.

```
    NSMutableArray *newArray =  [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *subDict in yourArray)
    {
     NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:subDict];
    [dict setObject:[self yourMethodToGetStatusFor:subDict] forKey:@"status"];
    [newArray addObject:dict];
    }
    self.yourArray = newArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < [mutableArray count]; i++) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[mutableArray objectAtIndex:i]mutableCopy];
        [dict setValue:@"YOUR_VALUE" forKey:@"status"];
        [mutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dict];
    }
```

Comment: this is going to replace what?

Comment: This code may get `crash`, if you try to convert `NSDictionary' object to 'NSMutableDictionary'...

Comment: @user2889249 This will add one more key-value pair.